# Easy way of creating categories

Tags: r

Suppose we have a two categorical variables  `A`  and  `B`  that can each take 6 values. So there are 36 possible combinations. I want to create a new variable  `category`  that enumerates these possibilities based on the values of  `A`  and  `B` . Is there a way of doing this without hard coding?

Comment: Do you mean something like `expand.grid`?

Answer (score 0):

`apply(expand.grid(unique(A), unique(B)), 1, paste, collapse="")`

From inmost function to the outmost:

- `unique`, returns unique vales of its argument
- `expand.grid`, returns a matrix which contains the Cartesian product of its components
- `apply`, applies a given function to the specified matrix/data-frame/... along the given dimension (`1` = rows, `2` = columns)
- `paste` concatenates strings or vector elements